# Same column names in JOIN getting "column not found" error in ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, fetch, resultset

I have three tables `firm`, `shipp` and `supplier`.

all three columns have same column names as `id`, `name`, `city` ... other.

And I have written a join like in java:

```
String Query = "SELECT s.name Sname,s.city Scity,f.name Fname,f.city Fcity,"
        +"su.name Suname,su.city Sucity "
        +"FROM `order_details` ot "
        +"INNER JOIN `order` o ON ot.odr_id = o.odr_id " 
        +"INNER JOIN `product` p ON ot.pro_id = p.id "
        +"INNER JOIN `firm` f ON o.firm_id = f.id "
        +"INNER JOIN `shipp` s ON o.shipp_id = s.id "
        +"INNER JOIN `supplier` su ON o.sup_id = su.id ";
```

`product`,`order` and `order_details` are the other tables that are used in join.

This query working in phpMyAdmin.

*But* in java `ResultSet` giving "column 'Sname' not found." error.

I have tried below solutions but these are not working for me:

1) [java.sq.SQLException: Column not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062453/java-sq-sqlexception-column-not-found)

2) [Strange SQLException: Column not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672412/strange-sqlexception-column-not-found?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

3) Many other but no one working

Error Stack:

> java.sql.SQLException: Column 'Sname' not found.
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)

And:

> SEVERE: null

Please help me!

Thanks In advance.

## Edit 1:

**Problem Reproduce:**

When I run it with fetching data only from one aliased table (e.g. `shipp`) then it fetches data fine:

```
SELECT s.name Sname,s.city Scity ... other query part
```

But as soon as I `SELECT` columns from other aliased tables (e.g. `shipp`, `firm`, and `supplier`) then it throws error exception written above (Column not found).

```
SELECT s.name Sname,s.city Scity,f.name Fname,f.city Fcity,
       su.name Suname,su.city Sucity ... other query part
```

**Note:** This query running fine in phpmyadmin but not running with `ResultSet` fetch.

And this is how I'm getting columns from `ResultSet` (`rs2`):

```
String firstColumn = "";
String secondColumn = "";

while(rs2.next()) {
    firstColumn = "Shipp to : ";
    firstColumn += rs2.getString("Sname") + rs2.getString("Scity") ;
    firstColumn += "Person : " + rs2.getString("Fname") +"+ "+ rs2.getString("Fcity");

    secondColumn = "Supplier : " + rs2.getString("Suname");
    secondColumn += rs2.getString("Suname");
    secondColumn += rs2.getString("Sucity");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide [a complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (with execution and reading the results)? Also, I wonder if you can reproduce this error with a simpler query (e.g. "select s.name Sname from `shipp` s")

Comment: @defaultlocale I have edited question .

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this problem. Please, post the complete example: 1) create tables from scratch; 2) post the minimal, but complete, executable code example (include the code you're using to access the column in resultset).

Comment: @defaultlocale edited question.

Comment: The equivalent code works fine on my machine :) Is this the complete query? Which version of mysql JDBC driver are you using to connect to database?

Comment: Why are you joining tables you don't need?`+"INNER JOIN \`product\` p ON ot.pro_id = p.id "` your not using `p` in any other place than the very join your set up it's not needed stop adding unnecessary load to your database server's CPU.

Comment: @MartinBarker that's product tables are necessary to me in join.

Comment: not in that query, it's not. As I said you're not using `p` other than in the join statement's on. so your not using the product in that query.

Comment: try s.name as Sname for the aliases.

Comment: regarding this error SEVERE: null have you tried to verify if the rs2 is null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your error message I assume that you are using `MySQL` with the latest connector.

You can utilize the [positional queries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)) if necessary, this is using the number on which position on which the element could be find for example:

```
rs2.getString(1);
```

(Yes the numbering starts at 1...) It should be equivalent to this (of course without the capitalization problem):

```
rs2.getString("Sname");
```

This way you have to know the position only, but if you look at case sensitivity in the database/driver is pretty much the question of settings. To get around most of the problems I write my queries in capital if possible and without a backtick `.

To explore your `ResultSet` object try the following:

```
Statement statement = ...;
String queryString = "SELECT s.name sname,s.city scity,f.name fname, f.city fcity, su.name suname, su.city sucity "
        +" FROM `order_details` ot "
        +" INNER JOIN `order` o ON ot.odr_id = o.odr_id "
        +" INNER JOIN `product` p ON ot.pro_id = p.id "
        +" INNER JOIN `firm` f ON o.firm_id = f.id "
        +" INNER JOIN `shipp` s ON o.shipp_id = s.id "
        +" INNER JOIN `supplier` su ON o.sup_id = su.id ";
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
int colCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
if (resultSet.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
        System.out.println("Col(" + i + ") '" + metaData.getColumnName(i) + "' value:" + resultSet.getString(i));
    }
}else{
   System.out.println("No row found.");
}
```

This snippet will print first results the columns and values which are returned by the driver you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Please check you have imported the correct jdbc connection package `com.mysql.jdbc.connection`. You could have imported `java.sql.connection` instead as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18795485/2071106)